# Make a form which users can print after filling

Tags: forms, infopath, usability, look-and-feel

I have a requirement as following. I need to create  Price Quotations, like filling in the Customer's Name, The product details and their prices and quantity. And at last a Ok button that would print the complete Quotation on A4 Paper. What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Somebody told me Infopath can help... Please suggest how to achieve this with minimum efforts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to use a PDF Form Creator, do your forms, add functionality and save it as PDF in any size you want. 
Adobe Acrobat is capable of doing so, but due the expensive cost, some free alternative like *PDF Forms Designer* is available through here :

http://pdfformsdesigne.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: I need to fill the forms on computer screen and then print the filled form. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course it is! But a PDF reader is needed. Use Adobe reader or any other pdf reader available.